# SWF File to HTML 5

Tags: html

I.m having the SWF File .i want to convert swf file to HTML5 file.

Is any there any opensource tool.?

Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 0):

try Gordon

http://paulirish.com/work/gordon/demos/

It converts flash swf to svg.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Google SwIffy](https://www.google.com/doubleclick/studio/swiffy/).

It is built exactly for doing that.